# Looking for open source code library which can add forum functionality to a website

Tags: library, web-services, forum

I am looking for some open source libraries which I can add to a website I'm building to give it a forum-like functionality.

Basically, I want some existing functional software which is open source which I can drop-in to a website.

The project was bootstrapped with Create React App and is currently hosted on Firebase

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [NodeBB forum software](https://nodebb.org/). They have different options that range from paid plans with free trial to an [Open Source option](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB). They even have free hosting for open source project communities that qualify, according to their [pricing page](https://nodebb.org/pricing).

I haven't tried it myself, but there's a good article describing one user's experience with it [here](https://medium.com/@samwsoftware/building-a-forum-with-react-and-node-242a2a3c2995).